# How to display all cart item under a Single key?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add all the items under a single `cartId` in Firebase but when I try to do it, It does not go under a single `cartId` but create a different `cartId` everytime.

Here is a Screenshot.
[image]

The first id is `UserId.` 
The second Id is `cartID`.
And the third Id is `ProductId`

Here is the Code:

```
 private void addProductToCart() {
    cartReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Product In Cart");
    cartID = cartReference.push().getKey();
    final Cart cart = new Cart(name, quantity, price, url, id, cartID);
    checkreference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Product In Cart").child(userID).child(cartID).child(id);
    checkreference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                Toast.makeText(DisplayProductDetails.this, "Already in Cart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                cartReference.child(userID).child(cartID).child(id).setValue(cart);
                Toast.makeText(DisplayProductDetails.this, "Added to Cart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(DisplayProductDetails.this, NavigationMenu.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I assumed that you were using Firebase Realtime Database.
Perhaps learning this line of code can help to solve this problem.

```
cartID = cartReference.push().getKey();
```

You are creating a new cartID and then assign it to every Cart object you create.
This will not be a problem if you only want to add one item to the cart, but if you are executing this code within a loop, then of course it will be a problem, since every cart item will be added to a new, different ID instead of your previously created cartID. Even if you are storing your cartID as instance/static variable like you did in that code, it will get overwritten especially when executed within a loop without performing any check.

You may want to add simple check as such:

```
if (cartID != null && cartID != "") {
      // check here if the cartID is null or it's not been set (equal empty string)
      // this is just an example, modify the condition that fits your use case
}
```

With this, as long as your cartID variable has already been set then any cart item will be assigned to that cartID.

Comment: I understand what is happening with cartID but how can I put products under a same cartID. I try the if condition but it didn't work

Comment: Are you going to put only one item or more than one? If there are many/more than one then of course you will be using a loop. I think the condition should be valid and working, but forgive me that I forgot to set an else condition to set the cartID if it's null or empty/blank.

Comment: Perhaps you can post your full code here so I can help further and see what's going wrong. You just added a method to add a product into a cart, but based on that code and your Firebase database image, I would say it's more likely the problem of overwriting the previously created cartID. In that way, your products (if there are more than one) will end up stored in a different cartID.